# Can i send html tag in subject when sending email in Rails

Tags: html, email, ruby-on-rails-4, tags

I am sending email in `rails 4 application.`

I am sending `body` text with `HTML tags` which convert into plain text like `<b>hello</b>` then its display BOLD in body but can i pass `HTML tags in subject` with same effect?

Like: I want to pass `<b>Offer</b>` in subject of email with bold effect then is it `possible` in rails 4?

any one have

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to style/format the subject of an email with font styles, weights, faces, color, etc.

Comment: Ok, i not found any where...so may be

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with HTML, as the subject is always just text.  One could, however, use UTF-8 characters to make the subject more noticeable.  The following example uses characters from the mathematical alphanumerical symbol set:

> UTF-8 Test:

Just place it in your subject string and make sure that the file's encoding is UTF-8 when saving.

The downside of this is that some mail clients will not support this.  Also, the fonts necessary to view this may not be installed on all computers.